# Programmer now given a cold call list on top of current workload. Time to leave?

Tags: software-industry, work-environment, job-change, work-experience

Edited to fit in Stack Guidelines:
I am a programmer with a heavy/healthy work load. I have 3 years of experience and since day 1 with this company I am at, I've been handling projects solo, from point A to point Z which includes everything from database design, to coding to phone-support.

I have now been given a call list. **Is this appropriate?** I am titled and paid as a programmer, **not** a software engineer+database administer+systems Analyst+Tech Support (and now)+*Sales guy*... **Is this to be expected as an entry level software engineer?**

Comment: Someone please change tags if those aren't appropriate. I am new to this meta, sorry :(

Comment: If you have to ask then yes you are nuts

Comment: I've seen frat keggers with better management practices.  If you think you're gaining a benefit from staying, then stay.  I can't see where you are, though.  I would, however, document all your issues.  Not for any legal reason, but I think you have the makings of a great comic strip, here.

Comment: You may want to mention the call list issue in the subject. I have been on sales calls when a customer had difficult technical questions. I thought the question was going to be about something like that. What you describe is very different.

Comment: Either you're severely underpaid, or they're really desperate for business, or both, if they think it's a good use of your time to basically be a phone salesman.

Comment: @Kai It's more of.. the new sales guy is horrible and it's been half a year since we've hired him and he hasn't closed a single bid yet. It was his idea to mass mail thousand and thousands of potential customers and now all of us programmers ( 6 of us including the intern ) are being dragged into his job.

Comment: Edited @PatriciaShanahan. Sorry, I see now how it may have been misleading.

Comment: Man, putting devs on cold-calls ...  You might as well just light the checkbook on fire.  There are dozens of cost-effective outsourcing agencies that are really good at this stuff.  Here's the first one I found with Google:  https://www.flatworldsolutions.com/call-center/cold-calling-services.php

Comment: ^^ lol and hence my nerd rage.... It's not like I don't have anything to do. I'm constantly busy and even now I'm on 'vacation' but have spent at least 8 hours today working from home.

Comment: I will clarify and say it's only 5-30 calls we need to do a day, but it's just the principle that irritates me.

Comment: Any company having their software programers being their sales staff is clearly out of cash. Time to get the resume updated.

Comment: also "only 5-30 calls"? That's pretty crazy.

Comment: "even now I'm on 'vacation' but have spent at least 8 hours today working from home" - why are you doing that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "on call?" You mean you make sale calls to customers? Or do you mean you carry a pager/phone for system outages from customers and so forth? If it is the former, heck yeah, quit now if they are making you a "jack of all trades" so to speak. If it is the latter, then that is not uncommon to be asked to carry a pager for system monitoring and correction.

Comment: You're already preparing to leave. Prepare to leave. Get your portfolio ready, etc. Then tell management you're a coder, not sales and you don't feel comfortable doing it. Tell them you're not willing to do the calls. What can happen? They can say fine, and hire someone else to do it and you're good. They can fire you, and you're already ready for that. No down side.

Comment: @DA. and if they're not out of cash, they're out of their minds! Ask a programmer about some system and they'll be honest - "its quite good, except the user input part which really needs a rewrite and its exception handling is non-existent. So do you want to buy it?"

Answer (score 8):

I think the consensus is that, as @Kai said, either you're massively underpaid or this company is desperate ... unless, *perhaps*, what you're developing is software for managing cold calls ... and unless you really think you can and want to rescue them, it probably does make sense to polish the resume and see what your other options are.

Comment: This is our new sales guy's idea. I think he's the desperate one, dragging us into his lack luster performance thus far. Pay is ~60k in Mid western state. Time to leave still even though I get to 'come and go' as I please? ? ?

Comment: That's something only you can decide. How much do you value that, how willing are you to cope with this,... "shoild I" questions are almost automatically offtopic on SE for just that reason. We don't have all the info we aren't you, we can't answer. Go not to the Internet fo value judgements, for it will say both "mu" and "ni!"

Comment: can 'should I' appropriately be changed for 'would you'?

Comment: And it's something your new sales guy talked Management into, which means it's still their responsibility. Unless this is all unauthorized, in which case I advise referring him to your manager.

Comment: I'm not there; I don't have all the data, I wouldn't be in that job, I don't know your finances or prospects...  Mu. This is not a question.

Comment: Could be "sales guy wants to skim extra commissions off of salaried dev resource" as opposed to "sales guy/company is desperate", if the call list wasn't authorized by management.